# Get every n-elements of array

Tags: arrays, ruby, iteration, enumeration

How to select every n-elements (e.g. six) of an array using Ruby 1.9+? Example:

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ... , 33]
# solution
# => [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11], ... ]
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

[`Enumerable#each_slice`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001514)

> Iterates the given block for each
>   slice of  elements. If no block is
>   given, returns an enumerator.
>
> e.g.:
>
> ```
> (1..10).each_slice(3) {|a| p a}
> # outputs below
> [1, 2, 3]
> [4, 5, 6]
> [7, 8, 9]
> [10]
> ```

Use as:

```
irb(main):002:0> a =  Array(1..33)
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33]
irb(main):003:0> a.each_slice(5) # no good
=> #<Enumerable::Enumerator:0x47ae6e8>
irb(main):004:0> a.each_slice(5).to_a # good
=> [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18, 19, 20], [21, 22, 23, 24, 25], [26, 27, 28, 29, 30], [31, 32, 33]]
```

Comment: Nice! I was looking exactly for this!